# Probability function when flipping two fair coins

Tags: probability

Consider flipping two fair coins. Let $X = 1$ if the first coin is heads, and $X = 0$
if the first coin is tails. Let $Y = 1$ if the second coin is heads, and $Y = 5$ if the second
coin is tails. Let $Z = XY$. What is the probability function of Z?

Solution: $P_z(0) = P_z(2) = 1/4$. With $P_z(1) = 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2$ and $P_z(z) = 0$ otherwise.

---

I don't understand the solution. Since $Z = XY$, then $P_z(0)$ is whenever $X = 0$ and $Y = 1$ or $Y = 5$

Could someone explain the solution to me step by step please and thanks

Comment: Are you saying that is the given solution or is it your solution?  Either way, it is wrong since $Z = 2$ is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probability distribution must sum to $1$. Like you have clearly stated, when $X=0$, $Y$ can take $2$ values and when $X=1$, $Y$ can take the same $2$ values. Now we exhaust all possible values of the new random variable $Z$, which will lead to the distribution for the new random variable $Z=XY$. Lets see what values $Z$ can take:

When $X=0$ and $Y=1$, $Z=XY=0 \cdot 1=0$

When $X=0$ and $Y=5$, $Z=XY=0 \cdot 5=0$

When $X=1$ and $Y=1$, $Z=XY=1 \cdot 1=1$

When $X=1$ and $Y=5$, $Z=XY=1 \cdot 5=5$

So $Z$ has $3$ possible values, $(0,1,5)$. The probability of $Z$ taking those values is defined in terms of the $X$ and $Y$ so we can write the probability of $Z$ like so:

$$P(Z=0)=P(X=0\cap Y=1)+P(X=0 \cap Y=5)$$

$$P(Z=1)=P(X=1 \cap Y=1)$$

$$P(Z=5)=P(X=1 \cap Y=5)$$

The $\cap$ operator essentially is an **AND** operator, where $A \cap B$ implies $A$ AND $B$ at the same time. So we have exhausted all possible combinations of $X$ and $Y$.

Now since $X$ is independent of $Y$, i.e. the result of $X$ has no effect on $Y$ and vice versa, we can say $P(X=x\cap Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$. We know $P(X=x)=P(Y=y)= \frac 12$ since both random variables represent the outcomes of flipping a fair coin. So out probabilities for $Z$ above, become:

$$P(Z=0)=P(X=0)P(Y=1)+P(X=0)P(Y=5)$$ $$=\frac 12 \frac 12+ \frac 12 \frac 12=\frac 14 + \frac 14= \frac 12$$

$$P(Z=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$$ $$\frac 12 \frac 12= \frac 14$$

$$P(Z=5)=P(X=1)P(Y=5)=\frac 12 \frac 12= \frac 14$$

To summarise in your form of the probability,

$$P_z(0)=\frac 12 \ ,\ P_z(1)=\frac 14 \ ,\ P_z(5)= \frac 14$$

Please let me know if I can clarify!